# Source for Adam being made with the letter Hey

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, creation, aleph-bet-letters, adam

I know of this gemarah teaching (see also Midrash Rabah 12:2) about Bereshit 2:4 which teaches that the phrase: 'Eileh toldot hashamayim v'ha'aretz b'hibaram' could be read as 'b'Hey baram', that HaShem created this world with the letter Hey.

R. Yitzchak Hutner (in Pachad Yitzchak to Sukkos) writes that the reason a "hei" was added was because Avraham was becoming a new creation, so to speak - being fashioned from new.

From these teachings it seems to me that the letter Hey represent 'creative power'.

Well I can't remember from where but I remembered comming across this teaching about Adam HaRishon being created with the letter Hey as well, that HaShem breathed with the Hey - the divine breath - into his nostrils the breath of life. That HaShem formed man of the dust of the ground and with this breath he became a new creation; a nefesh chayah. Anyone familiar with this teaching and knows it's source?

Comment: The world was created using the letter heh (Menachos 29a) - could that be where you heard Adam [along with everything else] was created with the letter heh?

Comment: @NJM That’s the first source he quoted. The difference is whether the derasha is from בהבראם or כי בי-ה ה׳ צור עולמים.

Comment: @NJM I think your right: it says that the Breath of His mouth refers to the letter Hey (בִּדְבַר יְהוָה, שָׁמַיִם נַעֲשׂוּ; וּבְרוּחַ פִּיו, כָּל-צְבָאָם. ). Probably someone connected it to the verse of Bereshit 2:7 “The human being became a living spirit” (Bereishit 2:7). Targum Onkelos translates this phrase to Aramaic: “V’havet b’Adam l’Ruach..."  and thus connects the word for breath with the ruach of Adam.